# Guide for migrating from Swiper 2.5.5 to 4.0.7?

Tags: upgrade, swiper.js

I'm looking for some kind of **guidelines, known issues, risks** or any kind of information to help migrating an app written using idangerous Swiper 2.5.5 to the latest (4.0.7 as of December 2017). My major concern is support for latest Chrome / FF for desktop, although mobile and other browsers are a plus.

I found this [Change Log](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) page with some release notes from version 3.0.0 on. I found nothing about older versions and no guide to upgrade, specially useful for major versions

---

Obs: [the same question](http://idangero.us/swiper/forum/#!/?Migration%20from%20Swiper%202.5.5%20to%204.0.7?) was originally posted on their forum

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few lessons learned after some initial tests (the list is most likely not complete). APIs updated:

1. jQuery/Zepto usage changed from `$('.swiper-container').swiper({})` to `new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {})`
2. `resizeFix()` removed
3. `reInit()` removed
4. navigation APIs renamed:

   - `swipeTo()` to `slideTo()`
   - `swipePrev()` to `slidePrev()`
   - `swipeNext()` to `slideNext()`
5. `pagination` param type changed from `'.tgt'` to `{ el: '.tgt'}` obj